# How can I make a searchable PDF from an PDF of scanned pages?

Tags: java, pdf, tesseract

How can I make a searchable PDF from an PDF of scanned pages using tesseract for my Java application?

Comment: what exactly u mean by searchable

Comment: i have recently worked on similar project so maybe can help

Comment: searchable pdf means u can select the text from your PDF usually it did not happen when your PDF contains scanned pages.

Comment: so are you getting scanned file as an image?

Comment: yes I am getting scanned files as an image if you can give me the code it will be very helpful.

Comment: This is stackoverflow, we will not write code for you. Show what you've done and tell us which problems you encountered.

Comment: Difference Between PDF and Searchable PDF

There is a key distinction between a regular PDF file and a searchable PDF file. Normally, when you scan a document and save it as a PDF, the text remains inaccessible. You can view it, but you cannot copy it, edit it, or save it in a text file because the characters are indistinguishable from the rest of the image.

Comment: when you convert the PDF document into a searchable PDF, all of the contents become accessible. This allows you to copy and paste text from the PDF into any other document for easy editing.   

@KumarSaurabh

Comment: answered below to ur specfic query. still any problem comment below

Comment: I don't think you will have an API for converting the images and read them as texts. Moreover, the question seems to be like how to do and do it for me instead of this is not working. People would answer if you can make it like this approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String image2Text(String imagePath)
  {
  dataPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/" + appContext.getPackageName() +  "/"; 
    File tessdata = new File(dataPath); 
   if (!tessdata.exists() || !tessdata.isDirectory())
   {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!");   
} 
     Bitmap image= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
  TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
  baseApi.init(dataPath, "eng"); 

baseApi.setImage(image);
      String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
      baseApi.end();


      return recognizedText;
  }
```

Comment: after getting text make it to a pdf file and using tesseract u can allow edit. problem is when u make pdf from image pdf is stored as image not as text and hence u cant edit

Comment: your program here returns the text.
It does not convert a PDF into searchable PDF.


Difference Between PDF and Searchable PDF

There is a key distinction between a regular PDF file and a searchable PDF file. Normally, when you scan a document and save it as a PDF, the text remains inaccessible. You can view it, but you cannot copy it, edit it, or save it in a text file because the characters are indistinguishable from the rest of the image. 
Searchable PDF allows you to copy and paste text from the PDF into any other document for easy editing.

Comment: thats the idea to convert pdf from text not image

Comment: here read this how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925856/convert-txt-file-to-pdf-using-itext-keep-formatting

Comment: I want an java code which do something like this

http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/

Comment: cant share my whole project. stack is to get an idea and approach not the whole project.

Comment: thanx @kumar-saurabh appreciate your help will look forward to it .

Comment: if u get stuck then ask with specific problem. cant just share my company code on stack. hope u understand

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using Gnostice XtremeDocumentStudio (for Java).
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=289&t=How_to_convert_scanned_images_to_searchable_PDF_using_OCR_in_Java

```
DocumentConverter dc = new DocumentConverter();
DigitizerSettings ds = dc.getPreferences().getDigitizerSettings();
ds.setDigitizationMode(DigitizationMode.ALL_IMAGES);
ds.setRecognizeElementTypes(RecognizeElementTypes.TEXT);

try {
  dc.convertToFile(
    "H:\\Screenshot-2.png", 
    "e:\\converted_image.pdf");
} catch (FormatNotSupportedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ConverterException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XDocException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I work at Gnostice.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Code snippet has been added.