# How to Convert .doc/.docx to pdf in java using POI..?

Tags: java, apache-poi, ms-office

> how to convert ms-document to PDF,  is there any example pls share
>   with me.. thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925856/convert-txt-file-to-pdf-using-itext-keep-formatting

check this also

http://karanbalkar.com/2014/01/convert-text-file-to-pdf-document-in-java/

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i will look at that...

Answer (score 0):

If you are requiered to use POI i guess you should take a look at org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter 
I never tried this, but i guess it´s worth a try atleast.
It seems like you can use `WordToFoConverter`to convert your XWPFDocument to a FO-file ([example here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjABahUKEwjj4-mnxNrHAhVGPxoKHa7HDxU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsvn.apache.org%2Frepos%2Fasf%2Fpoi%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fscratchpad%2Ftestcases%2Forg%2Fapache%2Fpoi%2Fhwpf%2Fconverter%2FTestWordToFoConverter.java&usg=AFQjCNHXTpzxcskX3UcaGhmZtDY78nxvUw)).
From there you can use apaches FOP to transform the FO-file to a PDF like this:

```
// Step 1: Construct a FopFactory
// (reuse if you plan to render multiple documents!)
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

// Step 2: Set up output stream.
// Note: Using BufferedOutputStream for performance reasons (helpful with FileOutputStreams).
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Temp/myfile.pdf")));

try {
  // Step 3: Construct fop with desired output format
  Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);

  // Step 4: Setup JAXP using identity transformer
  TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); // identity transformer

  // Step 5: Setup input and output for XSLT transformation
  // Setup input stream
  Source src = new StreamSource(new File("C:/Temp/myfile.fo"));

  // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
  Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

  // Step 6: Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
  transformer.transform(src, res);

} finally {
  //Clean-up
  out.close();
}
```

This Code was taken from https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/embedding.html incase you want to read more on this topic.

Comment: No @moli there is no way you can convert your XWPFDocument to a FO file, because the WordToFoConverter is limited to the (old) HWPFDocument... (indeed the link you give IS the example for HWPFDocument only!!!)

Comment: You say "if you are required to use POI" what do you suggest instead ...